# Не удается добавить миграцию

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Существуют классы  `GropsAndProducts`, `Groups`, `Products`:

```
    public class GropsAndProducts
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Products")]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Groups")]
        public int GroupId { get; set; }

        public Groups Groups { get; set; }
        public Products Products { get; set; }
    }

    public class Groups
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Discription { get; set; }
        public List<GropsAndProducts> groupAndProducts { get; set; }
    }
    public class Products
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        // Еденица измерения
        [Required]
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Count { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Discount { get; set; }
        public string Discription { get; set; }
        public List<GropsAndProducts> groupAndProducts { get; set; }
    }
```

К ним есть контекст:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySite.Models;
using System.Data;

namespace MySite.Data
{
    public class DbProductsAndGroupsContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbProductsAndGroupsContext(DbContextOptions<DbProductsAndGroupsContext> option) 
            : base (option)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Products> products;
        public DbSet<Groups> groups;
        public DbSet<GropsAndProducts> gropsAndProducts;
    }
}
```

А так же настройка:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DbProductsAndGroupsContext>(option => 
            option.UseMySql(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), x=> x.MigrationsHistoryTable("__MyMigrationsHistory", "mySchema"))
                );
            services.AddDbContext<DbUserContex>(options =>
                options.UseMySql(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<Users>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbUserContex>();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Теперь о проблеме:

Первая миграция (От `UserIdentity`) выполнилась нормально (т е создалась новая БД а так же таблицы с записями). Но после того как я создал второй контекст и пытаюсь выполнить команду (в менеджере пакетов) `EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration -name:asdf -context:DbProductsAndGroupsContext`, то добавляется **пустая** миграция. Почему может так быть??? Буду рад любой информации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина в том что надо было писать в контексте не так:

```
        public DbSet<Products> products;
        public DbSet<Groups> groups;
        public DbSet<GropsAndProducts> gropsAndProducts;
```

А так:

```
        public DbSet<Products> products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Groups> groups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GropsAndProducts> gropsAndProducts { get; set; }
```